# going in and out in the same way with transition custom effect

Tags: css, css-transitions

i got this CSS3 sheet and i have a little problem with it

i need to make it to go out in the same way it is going in, i mean look at it when it gonna drop dow

```
@-moz-keyframes custom_effect {
    0% { height: 60px;}
    100% {height: 225px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes custom_effect {
    0% {height: 60px;}
    100% {height: 225px;}
}

ul#nav-drp li:hover {
    -moz-animation-name: custom_effect;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 4;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -webkit-animation-name: custom_effect;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

i can't make it go out in the same way it comes to go in, i tried to replace (`-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;`) with (`-webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;`)
but i didn't work
could you please describe what was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correct, but when you say "go out in the same way it comes to go in" it sounds that you want it to animate back to `height: 60px;` when you hover out? If so, that won't be possible with keyframe animations. As soon as you hover out the animation will stop and the element will jump back to it's original state.

This is however possible to solve using transitions instead.

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sS7Ud/5/) and here's the code from my example:

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>​
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #005ca1;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s;
       -moz-transition: height 1s;
        -ms-transition: height 1s;
         -o-transition: height 1s;
            transition: height 1s;
}

.box:hover {
    height: 225px;
}
```

In this case I've set `height` as the property I want to `transition` with a duration of `1s;` and I've added it to the element I want to transition, which will transition the height "both ways". In this case I've written the transition in short form, but for clarification the code in long form would look like this:

```
transition-property: height;
transition-duration: 1s;
```

It is also possible to add timing functions etc, but I tried to keep it simple in my example.

Hope that helps!

Comment: it is helps a lot, thank you you just saved me
but since i didn't get the last part, i need to do some search for the long form in order to make it more advanced, but still you helped me a lot. thank you man, and i will take my turn to do some search for `transition-property: height;` and `transition-property: height;`

Comment: well, i have just one more question, is it possible to increase the expended width, just the expended width and not the .box width, because, i am trying to make it similar to ibm.com drop down menu

Comment: Yes, it's possible to transition the 'width' together with 'height', if that's your question? Add 'width' to 'transition: height 1s, width 1s;' and then just set the 'width' you want when you hover over the element. Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sS7Ud/8/

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was helpful. If not, let me know if there is something that you want me to clarify.

Comment: it was helpful, although i didn't use it, but to be available in answers section

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
transition-timing-function:linear;
```

try changing the transition-timing-function from ease to linear...

Because 'ease' property will have a slow start then little bit faster and at the end it will become slow again... so you wont get the same effect as going in and going out...

But, 'linear' property will have the same effect from start till end...

Might work...

Comment: thank you, i've tried to change it to linear, it gives me very smooth effect, it is better than ease, i appreciate your help, but i hope it was the one im seeking for it

but if any one here knows how to make it go out in the same way that is going in?, even if it was little different effect, any thing to close the drop down in the same smoothly it is opens with